# Porque el setTimeout no se activa

Tags: javascript

En la funcion elegir color despues de comprobar si el click correspondio a la secuencia deberia activarse de nuevo iluminar secuencia con el numero de nivel acomulado, pero no hace nada, el debbuger no marca error ni la consola

*alguien sabe cuantas palabras necesitas para publicar? El sistema parece decirme cada vez que no son suficientes detalleas

orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam posuere ultrices tortor. Praesent porttitor ultrices diam id feugiat. Suspendisse augue leo, mollis vitae nisi suscipit, vehicula ullamcorper mauris. Vestibulum fringilla ligula arcu, eget euismod erat sagittis eu. Quisque non nibh id augue placerat porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tempor ornare consequat. Vestibulum et ligula dapibus, consequat massa vitae, porta justo.

```
> <script>




 const boton = document.getElementById('btnEmpezar')

    const verde = document.getElementById('verde')
  const amarillo =  document.getElementById('amarillo')
  const azul = document.getElementById('azul')
  const rojo = document.getElementById('rojo')
  const blanco = document.getElementById('blanco')
   let level = 0
   const ULTIMO_NIVEL = 10
    let subnivel = 0
   const colores = {
     verde, 
     amarillo,
     azul,
     rojo,
     blanco
   }
   
  
   let  secuencia = new Array(10).fill(0).map(n => Math.floor(Math.random() * 5))

 

  function hideButton(){
    
  boton.classList.add('hide')

 iluminarSecuencia()

  }

 function  iluminarSecuencia() {
 
               for (let i = 0; i <= level; i++) {
                 const color = transformarNumeroAColor(secuencia[i])
                 setTimeout(() => iluminarColor(color), 1000 * i)
                 console.log(color)
               }

               agregarEventosClick()
             }
          
          
     
       function  iluminarColor(color) {
               colores[color].classList.add('light')
               setTimeout(() => this.apagarColor(color), 350)
             }
     
         function    apagarColor(color) {
               colores[color].classList.remove('light')
             }

        function   transformarNumeroAColor(numero) {
               switch (numero) {
                 case 0:
                   return 'rojo'
                 case 1:
                   return 'verde'
                 case 2:
                   return 'amarillo'
                 case 3:
                   return 'azul'
                  case 4:
                  return 'blanco'
               }
}
 
function transformarColorANumero(color) {
               switch (color) {
                 case 'rojo':
                   return 0
                 case 'verde':
                   return 1
                 case 'amarillo':
                   return 2
                 case 'azul':
                   return 3
                 case 'blanco':
                  return 4
               }
             }




function agregarEventosClick() {
  
               colores.verde.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
               colores.amarillo.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
               colores.rojo.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
               colores.azul.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
               colores.blanco.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
             }
     

         function  elegirColor(ev) {
               const nombreColor = ev.target.dataset.color
               const numeroColor = transformarColorANumero(nombreColor)
               iluminarColor(nombreColor)
               if (numeroColor === secuencia[subnivel]) {
                 subnivel++
                 if (subnivel === level) {
                   level++
                   /*this.eliminarEventosClick()*/
                   setTimeout(iluminarSecuencia, 1500)
                   if (level === (ULTIMO_NIVEL + 1)) {
                     this.ganoElJuego()
                   } else {
                     
                   }
                 }
               } else {
                 this.perdioElJuego()
               }
             }


             


  </script>
```

Comment: El problema es que has puesto ***TODO*** tu código, y no un [mre] tal como se recomienda. Una buena pregunta tiene una descripción *CONCISA* del error/problema, el código para ejemplificar/demostrar dicho error y las soluciones que has intentado. No necesitamos ver todo el código que tienes, ***únicamente el suficiente para REPRODUCIR EL ERROR***. Así luego no tendrás que poner texto sin sentido en la pregunta para *rellenar*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que proporcionaste no está completo y fue un poco complicado trabajar con los datos que pasaste, pero se comprende que es un juego de memoria y el reto estuvo entretenido.

Tu problema es la forma en la que validas cómo pasas al siguiente nivel, debería ser algo como esto:

```js
if (numeroColor === secuencia[subnivel]) {
  subnivel++;
  if (subnivel > level) {
    level++;
    subnivel = 0; // reseteamos para que valide desde el inicio
    setTimeout(iluminarSecuencia, 1500);
    if (level === (ULTIMO_NIVEL + 1)) {
      alert("Ganaste!");
      showButton();
    }
  }
}
```

Observa que subes el nivel solo si el subnivel ya lo pasó, luego tienes que resetear para que valide desde el inicio.

Te anexo el código completo que utilicé, solo ten en cuenta que necesitas trabajar en la rutina de finalización del juego. No lo hice porque necesitas hacerlo tu y porque el problema que reportaste ya estaba resuelto.

EDIT: Preparé un artículo en mi sitio con la solución completa por si les interesa ver el juego funcionando: https://maestrosdelcodigo.com/aprende-programar-simon-javascript/

```js
const boton = document.getElementById('btnEmpezar')

        const verde = document.getElementById('verde')
        const amarillo = document.getElementById('amarillo')
        const azul = document.getElementById('azul')
        const rojo = document.getElementById('rojo')
        const blanco = document.getElementById('blanco')
        let level = 0
        const ULTIMO_NIVEL = 10
        let subnivel = 0
        const colores = {
            verde,
            amarillo,
            azul,
            rojo,
            blanco
        }

        let secuencia = new Array(10).fill(0).map(n => Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));

        function hideButton() {

            boton.classList.add('hide');
            iluminarSecuencia();
            agregarEventosClick();
        }
        
        function showButton() {
            boton.classList.remove('hide');
            level = 0;
            subnivel = 0;
        }

        function iluminarSecuencia() {

            for (let i = 0; i <= level; i++) {
                const color = transformarNumeroAColor(secuencia[i]);
                setTimeout(() => iluminarColor(color), 1000 * i);
                console.log(color)
            }
        }

        function iluminarColor(color) {
            colores[color].classList.add('light')
            setTimeout(() => this.apagarColor(color), 350)
        }

        function apagarColor(color) {
            colores[color].classList.remove('light')
        }

        function transformarNumeroAColor(numero) {
            switch (numero) {
                case 0:
                    return 'rojo'
                case 1:
                    return 'verde'
                case 2:
                    return 'amarillo'
                case 3:
                    return 'azul'
                case 4:
                    return 'blanco'
            }
        }

        function transformarColorANumero(color) {
            switch (color) {
                case 'rojo':
                    return 0
                case 'verde':
                    return 1
                case 'amarillo':
                    return 2
                case 'azul':
                    return 3
                case 'blanco':
                    return 4
            }
        }

        function agregarEventosClick() {

            colores.verde.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
            colores.amarillo.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
            colores.rojo.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
            colores.azul.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
            colores.blanco.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
        }

        function elegirColor(ev) {
            const nombreColor = ev.target.dataset.color;
            const numeroColor = transformarColorANumero(nombreColor);
            iluminarColor(nombreColor);
            if (numeroColor === secuencia[subnivel]) {
                subnivel++;
                if (subnivel > level) {
                    level++;
                    subnivel = 0; // reseteamos para que valide desde el inicio
                    setTimeout(iluminarSecuencia, 1500);
                    if (level === (ULTIMO_NIVEL + 1)) {
                        alert("Ganaste!");
                        showButton();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                alert("Perdiste!");
                showButton();
            }
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        #verde { background-color: green }
        #azul { background-color: blue }
        #rojo { background-color: red }
        #amarillo { background-color: yellow }
        #blanco { background-color: white }
        .light { background-color: aqua !important }
        .hide { display: none }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnEmpezar" onclick="hideButton()">Empezar</button>
    <div>
        <button id="verde" data-color="verde">verde</button>
        <button id="amarillo" data-color="amarillo">amarillo</button>
        <button id="azul" data-color="azul">azul</button>
        <button id="rojo" data-color="rojo">rojo</button>
        <button id="blanco" data-color="blanco">blanco</button>
    </div>

</body></html>
```